# hello world in APUE Chapter 7 exit with code 0

Tags: c++, c, macos, unix

APUE chapter 7 says this snippet would exit with exit code other than 0 (13 in example). But it exit with code 0 on my computer:

```
#include    <stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("hello, world\n");
}
```

Compile & Running environment:

`Darwin cuixiaochens-MacBook-Pro.local 17.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 17.4.0: Sun Dec 17 09:19:54 PST 2017; root:xnu-4570.41.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64`

Gcc version:

`♪  apue.3e git:(master) gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin`

Comment: APUE is rather old now, and the code you show is no longer really valid C code. The only thing is that no explicit `return` in `main` is needed (since the C99 standard).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But even if I compile program with -std=c89, the program still exit with code 0

Comment: @XiaochenCui read my answer. Main with no return returns zero

Comment: @XiaochenCui even if we consider any other function and we forget the return statement the function may return **any value** including zero as well. So even in this case your book is wrong

Comment: @P__J__ That's coincidental. It was not standardized before the C99 standard, and as such is either pure "luck" or a compiler-specific extension.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude As I wrote `standard no older than 20 years` which is more than the age of most OPs

Comment: @P__J__ I know what you said is right, and the APUE also mentioned that program will exit with code 0 when build using -std=c99. But I want to figure out why the program exit with code 0 when build using -std=c89

Comment: Because it is an UB. Any value is possible. In your case 0. If you make main less trivial it is very likely to be something else. Do not try to figure why the UB is giving a particular result as it is pointless

Comment: Ps it is the UB in the pre c99 standard of course

Comment: @P__J__ I don't agree that "trying to figure why the UB is giving a particular result" is pointless.  You do have to keep in mind that it could give a completely different result on a different CPU or compiler, but understanding what the machine code generated for a particular instance of UB actually does is valuable to a deeper understanding of both the language and the hardware.

Comment: @zwol not at this stage of learning. Now it only brings the mess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

APUE is trying to illustrate a real phenomenon, and it's still possible to observe that phenomenon with a modified program.

Normally, when a function declared to return a value (i.e. return type other than `void`) returns by "falling off the end", its return value is "indeterminate," and a program that observes that value has "undefined behavior."  A common way for that undefined behavior to manifest, is for the function's return value to be equal to the return value of the last call made within the function, because that value is still in the return-value register.  APUE was trying to demonstrate this by falling off the end of `main`, but since C99 there is a special rule for falling off the end of `main` which says that this behaves as-if `main` had properly returned 0.  Many compilers apply this rule even in their C89 mode, since in C89 it was undefined, so they're allowed to do anything they like.

So, to observe the phenomenon APUE wants you to observe, you need to use a function other than `main`, and you also need to take steps to prevent interprocedural analysis, such as splitting the program into two translation units and then not using link-time optimization.

```
/* file1.c */
#include <stdio.h>

int print_hello(void)
{
    printf("hello world\n");
}

/* file2.c */
#include <stdio.h>
extern int print_hello(void);

int main(void);
{
    int n = print_hello();
    printf("print_hello returned %d\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile each file separately with e.g. `cc -c` and then link them together as a third operation.  On my computer, with my compiler, this prints

```
hello world
print_hello returned 12
```

Please do keep in mind that this program does have undefined behavior.  On a computer with a different calling convention (e.g. a SPARC) it might print a garbage number; if I had allowed interprocedural optimization to happen, the compiler might have deduced that the only way the program doesn't have undefined behavior is if it's never run, and therefore emitted *no code at all* for it.

(The program would *not* have undefined behavior if the value returned by `print_hello` was never used.  This is another special case in the language, for the sake of backward compatibility with code written before `void` return types were a possibility.)

Answer (score 1):

Tour APUE chapter is wrong. The main function in the C language is guaranteed by the standard to return zero if there is no return statement( if we consider standard no older than 20 years)